# Increment counter on every method call of class

Tags: javascript

This is a simple problem but somehow I am unable to figure out what's going wrong here.

```
class MyClass {
    constructor() {
        this.id = 0;
    }

    myFunc() {
        let newValue = this.id + 1;
        console.log('New Value', newValue);
    }

}

let myObj = new MyClass();
myObj.myFunc();  // New Value 1
myObj.myFunc();  // New Value 1
myObj.myFunc();  // New Value 1
```

I want `id` to increment every time `myFunc` is called so that it prints *1, 2, 3...*

Comment: Update `id` also: `this.id = this.id + 1;`

Comment: `this.id++;`...

Answer (score 0):

I think what your code supposed to be is like this:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor() {
      console.log('setting to 0');
        this.id = 0;
    }

    myFunc() {
        this.id += 1;
        console.log('New Value', this.id);
    }

}

let myObj = new MyClass();

myObj.myFunc(); // New Value 1
myObj.myFunc(); // New Value 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Increment {
    constructor() {
        this.id = 0;
    }
    myFunc() {
        this.id++;
        console.log(this.id)
    }
}
let myObj = new Increment();
myObj.myFunc();  
myObj.myFunc();  
myObj.myFunc();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.